# Force drupal 7 to place "www" in front of urls

Tags: 7, uri

there is a problem when a use logs in after typing "domain.com", clicks on a internal link that leads to "www.domain.com/somthing" and they are no longer logged in until they navigate to "domain.com" again. I just want the system to force the url to add the www at the beginning.

Comment: This is not a question about Drupal, as the answer given here is valid for any website running on Apache, including the ones using Wordpress.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding this to your .htaccess file will do it...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.YOURDOMAIN\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.YOUDOMAIN.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that .htaccess can be overwritten by upgrades.  A better place for this rule is the Apache config file.

Comment: In Drupal 6 this rule is already in the default `.htaccess` file. You just have to uncomment it. I guess it's the same in Drupal 7.

Answer (score 3):

@New Talk is correct.

In Drupal 7 uncomment these lines:

```
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Line 83 and 84.

@MPD is also correct. You will need to re-uncomment these everytime you update your drupal core version.