# How to make all menu links without www? (shortened menu links)

Tags: uri

I've seen a few sites, not necissarily Drupal sites, in which the menu links, are without `www.` (that is the [Cname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) [DNS record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types)).

Drupal 7 shortens links from `http://www.barackobama.com` to be `www.barackobama.com`

I am asking if it is possible to create links without the Cname even, I.E that the final result would be:

```
barackobama.com
```

Can be done from inside the Drupal GUI? If not, please at least example how will you do so from the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is something that is been handle at the server or DNS level. From the GUI, you do not have control of where you application (Drupal) can will run.

If you are running Apache you can add this code to your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^your-site.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.your-site.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Source: [Force drupal 7 to place "www" in front of urls](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17144/force-drupal-7-to-place-www-in-front-of-urls)

Comment: How will you do so from the .htaccess (Hope it's okay by you, that I ask here to expand your answer with that data)...

Comment: Benia, I have added the information on how to do it from the .htaccess.